# how to fetch a variable outside of the observable in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, observable

I have an Observable which has an array. I want to fetch that array outside of the Observable so that I can merge it with another array.

```
    this.builderService.getCommercialData()
     .subscribe(
       data=>{
        this.commercialDetails = data;
        this.commercialDetailsArray.push(this.commercialDetails);

       console.log(this.commercialDetailsArray);
       this.newcommercialDetailsArray = 
                             this.commercialDetailsArray[0];
       const arrayLength = this.commercialDetailsArray.length;
         if (arrayLength < 1) {
          this.loaderStatus = false;
          this.dataLoaded = false;
          this.noData = true;
          } else {
            this.loaderStatus = false;
            this.dataLoaded = true;
            this.noData = false;
          }
        },
      error=>{},
     );
```

I want to fetch `newcommercialDetailsArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have done it using Angular 2

ts file

```
 ngOnInit() {

       this._basicService.getBasic().subscribe(
       data => {

           this.basicResponse = data;

           console.log(this.basicResponse);

           return this.basicResponse;

    }
  )
  }
```

> I have get the data from service and put into basicResponse and just return the data from subscribe function console it to another onclick function to check that basicResponse if coming or not.

```
 save()
     {
       console.log(this.basicResponse)
    }
```

> Just return the values.It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot access the array outside of the subscribe with the actual data as beacause it is a
>   async callback and you want to access it in a synchronous way . you
>   can merge the array inside of the subscribe using the following

```
    myArray = [];

    this.builderService.getCommercialData()
     .subscribe(
       data=>{
        this.commercialDetails = data;
        this.commercialDetailsArray.push(this.commercialDetails);
       this.newcommercialDetailsArray = 
                             this.commercialDetailsArray[0];

       // do the merge here ;
       let myNewArray = 
       this.newcommercialDetailsArray.concat(this.myArray)   ;    
       const arrayLength = this.commercialDetailsArray.length;
         if (arrayLength < 1) {
          this.loaderStatus = false;
          this.dataLoaded = false;
          this.noData = true;
          } else {
            this.loaderStatus = false;
            this.dataLoaded = true;
            this.noData = false;
          }
        },
      error=>{},
     );
```

**Update**

If there are two observables that you need to run in order to generate the data you might need to look at `observables.forkJoin()`

> Fork Join The forkJoin() operator allows us take a list of Observables
>   and execute them in parallel. Once every Observable in the list emits
>   a value the forkJoin with emit a single Observable value containing a
>   list of all the resolved values from the Observables in the list.

More on [**`fork join`**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs) with example.

Comment: i can't because i have another observable which has that  array to be merged with this one , due to this reason i want to fetch the arrays outside

Comment: you should have mentioned this in the question , updating the answer